# Azre Data Explorer Data Connection Automation

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-data-explorer

Is there anyway to automate the creation of an Azure Data Explorer Data Connection. 
 I want to create it as part of an automated deployment so either ARM or through C#.  The Data Connection source is an EventHub and needs to include the properties specifying the table, consumer group, mapping name and data format.

I have tried creating a resource manually and epxporting the template but it doesn't work.  I have also looked through the MSFT online documentation and cannot find a working example.

This is all I have found [example](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/resources/templates/?resourceType=Microsoft.Kusto)

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at [this](https://github.com/aribornstein/AzureDataExplorerTutorial/blob/master/2_Ingesting_Stream_Data_and_Querying.ipynb) good example which shows how to create control plane resources (cluster, database, data connection) using ARM templates, and using a data plane python API for the data plane resources (table, mapping).

In addition, for C# please see docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.kusto.dataconnectionsoperationsextensions?view=azure-dotnet) and following C# example for how to create an event hub data connection:

```
var dataConnection = managementClient.DataConnections.CreateOrUpdate(resourceGroup, clusterName, databaseName, dataConnectionName,
            new EventHubDataConnection(eventHubResourceId, consumerGroup, location: location));
```

Comment: Thanks for the examples.  I get the same error both ways though via ARM "InternalServerError" and "Encountered internal server error. Please try again." via C#.  I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: Internal server error is not expected. Please open a ticket and MS will look at it.